# CMD Find a filename in directory with patter as ABC-[*].zip

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

How do I find all the files in the directory starting with `ABC` and ending with `.zip` in CMD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I find all the files in the directory starting with ABC and ending with .zip

Use `dir` with a wildcard as follows:

```
dir ABC*.zip
```

> **Wildcard matching rules**
>
> `*` Generally matches any 0 or more characters, with one exception
>   (see next rule). The non-greedy wildcard is free to match as many or
>   as few characters as are necessary for the remainder of the mask to
>   match.
>
> `*.` At end of mask matches any 0 or more characters except for {dot}.
>   In actuality, the rule applies with any number of `{dot}` and
>   `{space}` characters between the `*` and terminal `{dot}`. The regular
>   expression for this term is `[*][. ]*[.]$`

Source [Wildcards - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Dir - list files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [Wildcards - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html)